# SvelteKit: How to call mongodb without using endpoints?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, svelte, sveltekit

(1/9/2023) **Update** : SvelteKit now supports [server only load functions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#universal-vs-server) and [Form actions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions) to send requests to the server.

---

I want to call my database, but I don't want it be able to get accessed by end users by them going to the API endpoint that I set up. I was wondering how I would be able to just call my database from a file in the lib folder and just returning the data there. When I try it I get the error `global not defined`:

lib/db.js:

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

const uri = process.env["MONGODB_URI"];
const options = {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (!uri) {
  throw new Error("Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local");
}

if (process.env["NODE_ENV"] === "development") {
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}
export default clientPromise;
```

routes/items/index.js:

```js
import clientPromise from "$lib/db";

export async function get() {
  const client = await clientPromise;
  const db = client.db();
  const data = await db.collection("items").find({}).toArray();
  const items = data.map(({ name }) => ({ name }));

  if (items) {
    return {
      body: {
        items,
      },
    };
  }
}
```

My attempt:
lib/stores/items.js

```js
import clientPromise from "$lib/db";
import { writable } from "svelte/store";
export const items= writable([]);

const fetchItems = async () => {
  const client = await clientPromise;
  const db = client.db();
  const data = await db.collection("items").find({}).toArray();
  const items = data.map(({ name }) => ({ name }));

  substances.set(items);
};

fetchItems();
```

Trying the above code in various places always yields a `global not defined` error in the client.

I found one question from someone with the same problem, but I couldn't figure out how to create a helper file.

Comment: Just curious, can you explain more why you can’t use an endpoint? Are you trying to “protect” this data, as in from something like scraping/bots? Can you not just return only the data you need/want to render?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Yes that is pretty much it, I want to learn how to protect the API so no one can just use it as direct a data source except for my website.

Comment: Then it may be worth it to implement auth such as oauth (cookies). That being said, you could try inspecting the request object in the endpoint and see if you can determine whether the request came from a load function on the same domain or from an external source. If you can differentiate, can return an error.

Comment: FWIW I tried to do this a few different ways and didn't get what I wanted. The issue I kept hitting is that the connection pool to MongoDB needs to be set up somewhere. This can be done conditionally in the handle hook, but the first page load when the app starts will be really slow. Using endpoints from there wasn't too difficult, but response times were flaky. I ended up splitting the API into it's own Node server and just using sveltekit for routing and code splitting and it's working well. Once Sveltekit gets a hook for app start instead of just first page load I might revisit this.

Answer (score 1):

Protecting API is done on back-end side. Usually it either server (like NodeJS) or tools Nginx/Apache (proxy, etc.). You're basically looking for Content-Security-Policy topic, which is vaporous but not related to SvelteKit.

Btw, calling DB directly from the Front-end wouldn't be secure and is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

To get data from any database, you should create [enpoint](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-endpoints)

For user authentication, you can create [`handle` hook](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#hooks-handle):

```
export async function handle({ request, resolve }) {
  let user = await authenticate(request) 

  request.locals.user = user
  request.locals.isAuthenticated = !!user

  if (request.path.startsWith('/api')) {
    if (!user) {
      return {
        status: 401,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          error: {
            message: 'Unauthorized'
          }
        })
      }
    }

  const response = await resolve(request)
  return response
}
```